# dataprovider testing values from database

Tags: mysql, testing, testng

How to pass a values that reads from mysql db to @DataProvider?

In my case i have to pass values that read from db to test method through @DataProvider

Answer (score 1):

The dataprovider is meant to pass values from your data source to your tests.  You can put the code of reading from your db and creating Objects in your method annotated with @DataProvider and specify this DataProvider in your test method.
Something to the effect

```
@DataProvider(name = "dbreaddata")
public Object[][] readDBData() {

//read from db - 
//create object[][]
// return Object[][];
}


@Test(dataProvider = "dbreaddata")
public void useAndTestData(Object a) {
 //Use data read from db
}
```

Read more @ http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders